# How can I preserve Jamun (Indian blackberry) without sugar?

Tags: food-preservation

I want to save [jamun fruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syzygium_cumini) for a diabetic person so I can't add sugar. Is there any means to store it for 6 months or so by adding salt/lemon or any other thing except sugar?

[image]

Comment: Salt or acid would likely do horrible things to flavor.

Answer (score 1):

I usually just puree the Jamun and freeze it. No need to add anything else. It stays good for 4-6 months in freezer